# PHP - pregreplace url

Tags: php, html-parsing, converters, bbcode

i am trying to use `preg_replace` on a url to an image in HTML format, and turn it into BBCode.

From: `<img src="http://website.com/char/sign/Name+Surname.png">`

To: `[sign]Name+Surname[/sign]`

Note: the filename of the png file can be just `Name`, it can contain a middle name like: `Name+Middlename+Surname`, it can also contain `-` and `%2527` like `Carl-Philips` or `Bob+Mc%2527Donalds`

So this is what I've tried so far, but it's not doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
$source = array(
    '#\<img src=\"http\:\/\/website.com\/char\/sign\/\>(.+).png\>#isU'
);

$new = array(
    '[sign]$1[/sign]'
);

$text = preg_replace($source, $new, $text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parser ([How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)) for these in the future. You have a few typos in your regex.

This should accomplish what you are after:

```
/<img src="http:\/\/website\.com\/char\/sign\/(.+?)\.png">/
```

Demo (with exmplanation of regex): https://regex101.com/r/sT6aG9/1

PHP Example:

```
$source = '/<img src="http:\/\/website\.com\/char\/sign\/(.+?)\.png">/';
$new = '[sign]$1[/sign]';
$text = '<img src="http://website.com/char/sign/Name+Surname.png">, <img src="http://website.com/char/sign/Bob-Robinson.png">, <img src="http://website.com/char/sign/Michael%2527Ross.png">';
$text = preg_replace($source, $new, $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
[sign]Name+Surname[/sign], [sign]Bob-Robinson[/sign], [sign]Michael%2527Ross[/sign]
```

PHP Demo: http://3v4l.org/WC5oJ